# On pdf generate getting Image not found or type unknown barryvdh\dompdf error

Tags: php, linux, laravel, dompdf

I am getting below error when generating a PDF in Laravel using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf package of laravel.

> Image not found or type unknown

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table
        {
            border-color: #000;
            color: #000;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }   
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;" cellpadding="3" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td  style="text-align: right; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; padding-left: 5px;">User Image</td>
            <td colspan="4" style="height: 50px;">
                <img src="/val/test/storage/images/profile_1611820816863.jpg" height="70">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Level

```
 $complete_html = '<above HTML>';
 $dompdf = new Dompdf();
                $dompdf->loadHtml($complete_html);
                $page_size = 'A4';
                $dompdf->setPaper($page_size, 'portrait');
                $dompdf->render();

                $file_name = 'test_dom';
                $dompdf->stream($file_name.'.pdf', array("Attachment" => 1));
```

I have reviewed other post on this topic and set "RemoteEnable" as true in dompdf config file and restarted the server but still getting this issue.

Edit
I have changed image path it is a shared folder path, not project or local path.
Also, file and folder path both have full permission to read and write(777) is already given

Comment: have you tried full url for the img src?

Comment: @FirdausNasir My image files are inside a storage folder or some shared network folder not in a public folder so I could not use full URL I can use absolute path only.

Comment: did the below answers resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of a file permission issue, Please check your BL server has all required access to read/write an image file from the shared location.

This could happen only if the server configuration could have been changed.

Comment: Also if not work try and run "php artisan storage:link" command on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Your class is wrong, to use [laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) you should call `PDF` or `\Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF`. and change `/test/example-app/storage/images/profile_1611820816863.jpg` to  real absolute path. if your image folder inside `app` folder you should change to `app_path('storage/images/profile_1611820816863.jpg')`. Below is working code using dompdf wrapper:

```
$pdf     = \Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::loadHtml('<html><head>
<style>
        table
        {
            border-color: #000;
            color: #000;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }   
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;" cellpadding="3" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td  style="text-align: right; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; padding-left: 5px;">User Image</td>
            <td colspan="4" style="height: 50px;">
                <img src="'.app_path('storage/images/profile_1611820816863.jpg').'" height="70>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body></html>');
$pdf->stream('test_pdf.pdf', array("Attachment" => 1));
```

if you want still use original dompdf without wrapper, you need to change image url to `app_path('/storage/images/profile_1611820816863.jpg')` and also set `chroot` to `app_path()`

below is my tested working code withoud wrapper:

```
         $complete_html = '<html><head>
<style>
        table
        {
            border-color: #000;
            color: #000;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }   
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;" cellpadding="3" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td  style="text-align: right; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; padding-left: 5px;">User Image</td>
            <td colspan="4" style="height: 50px;">
                <img src="'.app_path('/test/example-app/storage/images/profile_1611820816863.jpg').'" height="70>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body></html>';
 $dompdf = new \Dompdf\Dompdf();
 $options = $dompdf->getOptions();
$options->setChroot(app_path());
$options->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);
$dompdf->setOptions($options);

     $dompdf->loadHtml($complete_html);

     $page_size = 'A4';
     $dompdf->setPaper($page_size, 'portrait');
     $dompdf->render();

     $file_name = 'test_dom';
     $dompdf->stream($file_name.'.pdf', array("Attachment" => 1));
```

Comment: I have changed image path it is a shared folder path, not a project or local path.

Comment: so I think the problem is the image path is not accessible. you must give permission to that folder path. for simple practice(but bad) try to change chmod to 777 to all related folders and also image file itself. and dont forget to set `setChroot` too

Comment: Image folder and image both have 777 and also setChroot but no luck

Comment: How you set `chroot` , I tested and working if I set the right `setChroot`